# Assign jQuery handler to multiple DIV using variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, html, hover

I have a bunch of different DIVs in a menu that affect different things but they're all related by a "number". It works perfectly when I have them all separated but all the For and While loop attempts failed... The hover are applied during a "$(document).ready(function () {});"...

I'm just trying to clean up the code here and change this :

```
$("#slideMenu1").hover(function () {
  $("#slideMenu1Box").slideToggle("fast");
});

$("#slideMenu2").hover(function () {
  $("#slideMenu2Box").slideToggle("fast");
});

$("#slideMenu3").hover(function () {
  $("#slideMenu3Box").slideToggle("fast");
});

$("#slideMenu4").hover(function () {
  $("#slideMenu4Box").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

to something like :

```
for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {    
$("#slideMenu"+i).hover(function () {
  $("#slideMenu"+i+"Box").slideToggle("fast");
});
}
```

but I can't pull it off. Is it possible? Any idea?

Comment: Or you could use classes and dom hierarchy to do most of the work.

Comment: Read up on JavaScript closures http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: @Kevin B : That's what I kind of ended up doing with the answer below. For some reason I didn't really consider that and went straight for IDs and massive confusion. Thank you for your input!

Musa : Haven't heard about closures before. I'm gonna have to read that link...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way i would do it is using class selector or another selector.

```js
 $(".slideMenu").hover(function() {
   $(".slideMenuBox", this).slideToggle("fast")
 });
```

```css
 .slideMenu{
   display:block;
   height:20px;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideMenu1" class="slideMenu">
  <div id="slideMenuBox1" class="slideMenuBox">
    Menu1
  </div>
</div>
<div id="slideMenu2" class="slideMenu">
  <div id="slideMenuBox2" class="slideMenuBox">
    Menu2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. So basically you're just telling him to the do the hover on the slideMenuBox that belongs to this slideMenu. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you give all of your slidemenu's a class called "slidemenu" then reference them like this:

```
$(".slideMenu").hover(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, and I would suggest taking advantage of event delegation so you don't have loads of event handlers:

```
$("#someAncestor").on("mouseenter mouseleave", "[id^=slideMenu]", function () {
    $("#" + this.id + "Box").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

You could simplify that by using a common class name, and if you show your markup, there will be a way to get a reference to the appropriate `...Box` element without finding it by ID.

Some references:

- [The `.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [Attribute starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Also note the use of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. The `.hover()` method you're currently using is just shorthand for them, but you can't use it with `.on()`, hence the need to bind to both explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'll check out these links.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a common class to these elements?

It should really look something like this:

```
<html>
    <div class="slideMenu" option="1">
        <div class="slideMenuBox"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideMenu" option="2">
        <div class="slideMenuBox"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideMenu" option="3">
        <div class="slideMenuBox"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideMenu" option="4">
        <div class="slideMenuBox"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideMenu" option="5">
        <div class="slideMenuBox"></div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Then you can apply your event handler to all of them:

```
$(".slideMenu").hover( 
    function()
    {
        $(".slideMenuBox", this).slideToggle("fast");
    }
);
```

And you can still refer to them individually, if you need to:

```
$(".slideMenu[option='1']")
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing based on nearly the exact same answer a little minutes before yours. Thanks a lot for your input! :)